# How to improve my left-join syntax in javascript?

Tags: javascript

So I have the following function that performs an equivalent of right-join using primary keys `pKeys` in two arrays of objects.

This function works just fine but I want to know if there is a way to improve the performance of this or if there is a better way to accomplish this.

```
let arrayA = [{id: 1, name: 'ghasem'},
              {id: 2, name: 'ahmad'},
              {id: 43, name: ',mahmoud'},
              {id: 5, name: 'ola'}];
let arrayB = [{id: 1, leader: 'brittney', perf: 4.3},
              {id: 2, leader: 'brian', perf: 9.2, sales: 45},
              {id: 43, leader: 'steven', perf: 0.3},
              {id: 7, leader: 'joe', perf: 5.4}];
pKey = 'id'; //the primary key used for joining

for (element of arrayA) {
  for (other of arrayB) {
    if (element[pKey] == other[pKey]) {
      for (key in other) element[key] = other[key];
    }
  }
}

console.log(arrayA);
```

Comment: Title says "left join", question says "right join".

Comment: As per the example, it seems the left outer join is needed.

Comment: The innermost `for` loop can be replaced by `Object.assign()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementation of left, right, inner, and full joins which would work in linear complexity and avoid taking up too much memory via the use of [iterators and generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators) to lazily provide the values:

```js
/* helpers */
const get = prop => item =>
  item[prop];

function* concat(...iterables) {
  for (const iterable of iterables)
    yield* iterable;
}

function* map(mapper, data) {
  for (let item of data)
    yield mapper(item);
}

function* filter(predicate, data) {
  for (let item of data)
    if (predicate(item))
      yield item;
}

function* toEntries(keyMapper, valueMapper, data) {
  for (const item of data)
    yield [keyMapper(item), valueMapper(item)];
}

const toMap = (indexBy, data) =>
  new Map(toEntries(get(indexBy), x => x, data));
/* /helpers */

//JOIN implementation

/**
 * Function that combines two lists attempting to merge them when they overlap
 * @param {Iterable} keysToCombine - iterable with the keys to pickk
 * @param {string} pKey - key the lists to use for finding overlaps
 * @param {iterable} - objects to combine
 * @param {iterable} - objects to combine
 * @return {array} - items from botth where a and b where pKey matching keysToCombine. 
 * If an item exist in both places, it is merged into one object
 */
function combine(keysToCombine, pKey, a, b) {
  const mapA = toMap(pKey, a);
  const mapB = toMap(pKey, b);
  
  return Array.from(keysToCombine, key => 
    Object.assign({}, mapA.get(key), mapB.get(key))
  );
}

const leftJoin = (on, left, right) => {
  const ids = map(get(on), left);
  return combine(ids, on, left, right);
}

const rightJoin = (on, left, right) => {
  return leftJoin(on, right, left);
}
  
const innerJoin = (on, left, right) => {
  const leftIds = new Set(map(get(on), left));
  const intersectedIds = new Set(
    filter(
      x => leftIds.has(x),
      map(
        get(on),
        right
      )
    )
  );
  
  return combine(intersectedIds, on, left, right);
}
const fullJoin = (on, left, right) => {
  const unionIds = new Set(
    concat(
      map(get(on), left), 
      map(get(on), right)
    )
  );
  
  return combine(unionIds, on, left, right);
}

/// Usage

let arrayA = [{id: 1, name: 'ghasem'},
              {id: 2, name: 'ahmad'},
              {id: 43, name: ',mahmoud'},
              {id: 5, name: 'ola'}];
let arrayB = [{id: 1, leader: 'brittney', perf: 4.3},
              {id: 2, leader: 'brian', perf: 9.2, sales: 45},
              {id: 43, leader: 'steven', perf: 0.3},
              {id: 7, leader: 'joe', perf: 5.4}];


const leftJoinResult  = leftJoin ("id", arrayA, arrayB);
const rightJoinResult = rightJoin("id", arrayA, arrayB);
const innerJoinResult = innerJoin("id", arrayA, arrayB);
const fullJoinResult  = fullJoin ("id", arrayA, arrayB);

console.log("---left join result---");
console.log(leftJoinResult);
console.log("---right join result---");
console.log(rightJoinResult);
console.log("---inner join result---");
console.log(innerJoinResult);
console.log("---full join result---");
console.log(fullJoinResult);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

### Join implementation

#### `combine()`

A convenience function that will combine the results based on the join strategy. Since it accepts keys, we can pre-process the keys based on what kind of join is needed and then hand over to `combine()` to process the results.

#### `leftJoin()`

Straight forward enough - everything from `left`. If anything is present in `right` it is going to be merged. Items unique to `right` are not going to be considered.

#### `rightJoin()`

Just a flipped version of `leftJoin()` since the logic is exactly the same. By swapping what is `left` and `right` we get the correct functionality.

#### `innerJoin()`

Intersection of all keys from `left` and `right`. Only the overlapping keys are chosen.

#### `fullJoin()`

All keys from both `left` and `right` de-duplicated.

### Helpers

The generators are used to avoid the overhead of creating an entire new array with something like `data.map(item => item[indexBy]);` when the arrays are very big. The `map()`, `filter()` and `concat()` generators generally do the same as `arr.map()`, `arr.filter()` and `arr.concat()` but only supply results as needed, instead of eagerly constructing an entirely new array.

```
function* toEntries(keyMapper, valueMapper, data) {
  for (const item of data)
    yield [keyMapper(item), valueMapper(item)];
}

const toMap = (indexBy, data) =>
  new Map(toEntries(item => item[indexBy], x => x, data));
```

The `toEntries()` and `toMap()` similarly lazily generate a map without needing an initial memory reserved for the array that the Map constructor will consume.

Answer (score 0):

We can explore a better one, but it's obvious that by using a [HashMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) you can save one nested loop used for lookup and using [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) you can save another loop.

```js
let arrayA = [
    { id: 1, name: "ghasem" },
    { id: 2, name: "ahmad" },
    { id: 43, name: ",mahmoud" },
    { id: 5, name: "ola" },
];
let arrayB = [
    { id: 1, leader: "brittney", perf: 4.3 },
    { id: 2, leader: "brian", perf: 9.2, sales: 45 },
    { id: 43, leader: "steven", perf: 0.3 },
    { id: 7, leader: "joe", perf: 5.4 },
];
pKey = "id"; //the primary key used for joining

const rightMap = new Map();
arrayB.forEach((row) => {
    rightMap.set(row[pKey], row);
});

const joinedData = [];

for (element of arrayA) {
    let row = {};
    if (rightMap.has(element[pKey])) {
        row = rightMap.get(element[pKey]);
    }
    joinedData.push({ ...element, ...row });
}

console.log(joinedData);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arrayA = [{id: 1, name: 'ghasem'},
              {id: 2, name: 'ahmad'},
              {id: 43, name: ',mahmoud'},
              {id: 5, name: 'ola'}];
let arrayB = [{id: 1, leader: 'brittney', perf: 4.3},
              {id: 2, leader: 'brian', perf: 9.2, sales: 45},
              {id: 43, leader: 'steven', perf: 0.3},
              {id: 7, leader: 'joe', perf: 5.4}];
const pKey = "id";

function mergeDataUsingKeyProvided(id, dataSets) {
  // resusable function to carry operations for different dataSets
  
  return dataSets[0].map(each => {
        return {
          ...each, ...(dataSets[1].find((item) =>  item[id] === each[id]))
        }
})
}

arrayA =  mergeDataUsingKeyProvided(pKey, [arrayA, arrayB]);
console.log(arrayA);
```